# How to split data by different classes in python 3.6

Tags: python, pandas, split

since I have a dataset looks like this:

---

```
CLASS, value1
  A,     1
  A,    2
  A,     3
  A,     5
  B,     4
  B,     1
  B,     2
  C,     1
  C,     5
```

---

and I would like to split the dataset by CLASS into several sub-dataset.

for now I'm doing it one by one:

---

```
datasetA = dataset.iloc[0:4, :].values

datasetB = dataset.iloc[4:7, :].values
```

---

but since there are thousands of different CLASSes, I hope there's any function that helps me have this done.

I've found that `groupby` may be help but not yet figured out how to apply it. Any suggestion or solution please?

Answer (score 1):

For most applications, your `groupby` object returned by `df.groupby('CLASS')` *is* your collection of separate datasets, and there are lots of ways to do complex manipulations on a `groupby` object within `pandas` (see the two links at the bottom of this post).

However, if you want to do it explicitely and have access to each dataset individually, one way to do it would be splitting your `groupby` into a dictionary of datasets by iterating through your `groupby`:

```
datasets = {}
by_class = df.groupby('CLASS')

for groups, data in by_class:
    datasets[groups] = data
```

You can then access each individual dataset like you would access any value in a dictionary:

```
>>> datasets['A']
  CLASS  value1
0     A       1
1     A       2
2     A       3
3     A       5
>>> datasets['B']
  CLASS  value1
4     B       4
5     B       1
6     B       2
>>> datasets['C']
  CLASS  value1
7     C       1
8     C       5
```

Or, you can use the [`GroupBy.get_group()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.get_group.html) method:

```
by_class = df.groupby('CLASS')

>>> by_class.get_group('A')

  CLASS  value1
0     A       1
1     A       2
2     A       3
3     A       5
```

In any case, it's definitely worth reading [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) in order to understand what `groupby` is and how you can apply it to your task

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion here is best create `dictionary of Dataframes` with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('CLASS')))
print (dfs)
{'A':   CLASS  value1
0     A       1
1     A       2
2     A       3
3     A       5, 'B':   CLASS  value1
4     B       4
5     B       1
6     B       2, 'C':   CLASS  value1
7     C       1
8     C       5}

dfa = dfs['A']
print (dfa)
  CLASS  value1
0     A       1
1     A       2
2     A       3
3     A       5

dfc = dfs['C']
print (dfc)
  CLASS  value1
7     C       1
8     C       5
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is just a text file, and you want to read from that text file, here's what i would do. But, I store them in a dictionary, as I don't know the iloc commands you use to be honest. But if you don't have to do it with these commands necessarily, I think what I suggest does the job.

```
a_dictionary = {}
with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    next(my_file)
    for line in my_file:
        line = line.strip()
        key = line.split(',')[0]
        key = key.strip()
        value = line.split(',')[1]
        value = value.strip()
        a_dictionary[key] = a_dictionary.get(key, [])
        a_dictionary[key].append(value)
```

If you print the result:

```
print(a_dictionary)
```

The output is:

```
{'C': ['1', '5'], 'A': ['1', '2', '3', '5'], 'B': ['4', '1', '2']}
```

I hope I am answering the question!

Answer (score 0):

If you know your groups ahead of time you can use the following:

```
datasetA, datasetB, datasetC = (g for _,g in df.groupby('CLASS'))
```